# Setting up mongodb behind nginx

Tags: nginx, mongodb

I am trying to setup mongodb behind nginx, and below is the configuration I used. But I keep getting the following error when I reload nginx. Any help is appreciated.

**nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mongodb:1**

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 27020;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_timeout 20s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
    }

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:27017;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check nginx.conf where the sites-enabled files are included.

Thats probably done in the `http` section of the conf file, but the `stream` directive is only allowed in the `main` section as stated here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#stream

You have to move your directive in nginx.conf file itself:

```
user ...
...
http {
  ...
}
stream {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it fixed the error but I still can't access Mongo DB remotely from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    ....

}

stream {
    server {
        listen  27018;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
    }

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
        server localhost:27017;
    }
}

http {
...
}
```